# Building a very specific menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table defined as follows:

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="item1a">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="item2a">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="item3a">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="item4a">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="item5a">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="item6a">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Some addition content that is not a menu</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Each cell has it's own item because the content and width such content varies. For instance, here is the CSS associated with item1a

```
.item1a {height:36px; width:84px; background-image:url(/resources/images/item1a.png);}
.item1b {height:36px; width:84px; background-image:url(/resources/images/item1b.png);}
```

When someone hovers over a cell, I need to change the class from a to b. I am pretty confident I know how to do that. My real problem is, I don't know how to make a menu popup underneath the item. I need to use this tabular structure because of the specificty of the graphics. Can someone help me out? How should I address this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying you would like a sort of mini-menu to appear between the menu item clicked and the next one?

Comment: What if you generated all the menus as `<td>`s below each of their parents as hidden, and showed them on hover?

Comment: Can't you use `<li>`'s for menu's instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your classes `item1a, item2a...` are typos and you meant to type `item1 a`

```
$('td').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut); //make your more selector more specific 

function hoverIn() {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.removeClass('a').addClass('b');
  var hoverMenu = '<div class="hoverMenu">Rest of the HTML needed for the menu</div>';
  $this.append(hoverMenu);
}

function hoverOut() {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.removeClass('b').addClass('a');
  $this.children('.hoverMenu').remove();
}
```

Switches the classes on hover and adds a DIV to the TD bottom. You can move it around to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi John, Actually, the "a" and "b" are not types. Rather "item1a" is the default state. "item1b" is the hover state of the item. Does that change anything?

Comment: You shouldn't do it like that. Because then it's not a class at all and it becomes an ID. Why do you want the class to be that specific?